# Speeding up matlab for loop

Tags: matlab, performance, for-loop, differential-equations

I have a system of 5 ODEs with nonlinear terms involved. I am trying to vary 3 parameters over some ranges to see what parameters would produce the necessary behaviour that I am looking for.
The issue is I have written the code with 3 `for` loops and it takes a very long time to get the output.
I am also storing the parameter values within the loops when it meets a parameter set that satisfies an ODE event.

This is how I have implemented it in matlab.

```
function [m,cVal,x,y]=parameters()

b=5000;
q=0;
r=10^4; 
s=0;
n=10^-8;

time=3000;

m=[];
cVal=[];
x=[];
y=[];

val1=0.1:0.01:5;
val2=0.1:0.2:8;
val3=10^-13:10^-14:10^-11;


for i=1:length(val1)
    for j=1:length(val2)
        for k=1:length(val3)
        options = odeset('AbsTol',1e-15,'RelTol',1e-13,'Events',@eventfunction);
        [t,y,te,ye]=ode45(@(t,y)systemFunc(t,y,[val1(i),val2(j),val3(k)]),0:time,[b,q,s,r,n],options);

         if length(te)==1
             m=[m;val1(i)];
             cVal=[cVal;val2(j)];
             x=[x;val3(k)];
             y=[y;ye(1)];

         end   
        end

    end
end
```

Is there any other way that I can use to speed up this process?

Profile viewer results
[image]

I have written the system of ODEs simply with the a format like

```
function s=systemFunc(t,y,p)
        s= zeros(2,1);
        s(1)=f*y(1)*(1-(y(1)/k))-p(1)*y(2)*y(1)/(p(2)*y(2)+y(1));
        s(2)=p(3)*y(1)-d*y(2);
end
```

f,d,k are constant parameters.
The equations are more complicated than what's here as its a system of 5 ODEs with lots of non linear terms interacting with each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tommaso is right. Preallocating will save some time.

But I would guess that there is fundamentally not a lot you can do since you are running `ode45` in a loop. `ode45` itself may be the bottleneck.

I would suggest you profile your code to see where the bottleneck is:

```
profile on 
parameters(... )
profile viewer
```

I would guess that `ode45` is the problem. Probably you will find that you should actually focus your time on optimizing the `systemFunc` code for performance. But you won't know that until you run the profiler.

EDIT

Based on the profiler output and additional code, I see some things that will help

1. It seems like the vectorization of your values is hurting you. Instead of

   @(t,y)systemFunc(t,y,[val1(i),val2(j),val3(k)])

try

```
@(t,y)systemFunc(t,y,val1(i),val2(j),val3(k))
```

where your system function is defined as

```
function s=systemFunc(t,y,p1,p2,p3)
        s= zeros(2,1);
        s(1)=f*y(1)*(1-(y(1)/k))-p1*y(2)*y(1)/(p2*y(2)+y(1));
        s(2)=p3*y(1)-d*y(2);
end
```

2. Next, note that you don't have to preallocate space in the systemFunc, just combine them in the output:

   ```
    function s=systemFunc(t,y,p1,p2,p3)
       s = [ f*y(1)*(1-(y(1)/k))-p1*y(2)*y(1)/(p2*y(2)+y(1)), 
             p3*y(1)-d*y(2) ];
    end
   ```

Finally, note that ode45 is internally taking about 1/3 of your runtime. There is not much you will be able to do about that. If you can live with it, I would suggest increasing your 'AbsTol' and 'RelTol' to more reasonable numbers. Those values are really small, and are making ode45 run for a really long time. If you can live with it, try increasing them to something like 1e-6 or 1e-8 and see how much the performance increases. Alternatively, depending on how smooth your function is, you might be able to do better with a different integrator (like ode23). But your mileage will vary based on how smooth your problem is.

Comment: I changed the code as Tommaso Belluzzo has suggested. It reduces the time but still can't run it for the whole range of parameter values that I want. I ran the profile viewer. In that Total Time for the `parameters` is 82.863s. Then for `ode45` Total Time is 82.776s, self time 37.946s. For `t,y,[val1(i),val2(j),val3(k)])` Total time 32.134s self time 15.868s. For `parameters>systemFunc` Total and self time 16.265s. So I think much time is spent in ode45. In the profile viewer is it Total time or self Time that I have t look into?

Comment: Can you add the profile screenshot to the post? Hard to decifer from just text

Comment: I included the profile viewer results to the post and the way I have written the ode system

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I removed vectorization but when trying to remove preallocation within `systemFunc` I get an error as `@(t,y)systemFunc(t,y,val1(i),val2(j),val3(k)) must return a column vector`. I thought usually vectorization and preallocation reduces time. So can I know why you suggested in this case  it takes more time.

Comment: Also, I increased the tolerance a bit because I saw that when there is no tolerance it runs much faster. But I can't remove it entirely as ode45 with reduced tolerance is used because the solutions vary over a vast range from 10^8 to 1 and that caused solver issues. Do you have any idea for how long it is acceptable for these kind of problems to take to run?

Comment: Vectorization reduces time if you are using a matrix operation. You were accessing the elements individually, and the initialization was wasting time creating an unnecessary object

Comment: There is no such thing as a "standard" time required  for ode45. It is very problem dependent and I know nothing about the system you are solving

Answer (score 3):

I have two suggestions for you.

1. Preallocate the vectors in which you store your results and use an
   increasing index to populate them into each iteration.
2. Since the options you use are always the same, instantiate then
   outside the loop only once.

Final code:

```
function [m,cVal,x,y] = parameters()

    b = 5000;
    q = 0;
    r = 10^4; 
    s = 0;
    n = 10^-8;
    time = 3000;
    options = odeset('AbsTol',1e-15,'RelTol',1e-13,'Events',@eventfunction);

    val1 = 0.1:0.01:5;
    val1_len = numel(val1);
    val2 = 0.1:0.2:8;
    val2_len = numel(val2);
    val3 = 10^-13:10^-14:10^-11;
    val3_len = numel(val3);
    total_len = val1_len * val2_len * val3_len;

    m = NaN(total_len,1);
    cVal = NaN(total_len,1);
    x = NaN(total_len,1);
    y = NaN(total_len,1);
    res_offset = 1;

    for i = 1:val1_len
        for j = 1:val2_len
            for k = 1:val3_len
                [t,y,te,ye] = ode45(@(t,y)systemFunc(t,y,[val1(i),val2(j),val3(k)]),0:time,[b,q,s,r,n],options);

                if (length(te) == 1)
                    m(res_offset) = val1(i);
                    cVal(res_offset) = val2(j);
                    x(res_offset) = val3(k);
                    y(res_offset) = ye(1);
                end

                res_offset = res_offset + 1;
            end
        end
    end

end
```

If you only want to preserve result values that have been correctly computed, you can remove the rows containing `NaNs` at the bottom of your function. Indexing on one of the vectors will be enough to clear everything:

```
rows_ok = ~isnan(y);
m = m(rows_ok);
cVal = cVal(rows_ok);
x = x(rows_ok);
y = y(rows_ok);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. It still takes a very long time to run

Comment: As @bremen_matt said, the main problem must be searched into the other functions being called within the one you posted with a profiler. They probably have a much higher impact, but since we can't see them, we can't optimize them.

Comment: I included the profile viewer results to the original post and the way I used to write the ode system.

Answer (score 0):

In continuation of the other suggestions, I have 2 more suggestions for you:

- You might want to try with a different solver, ODE45 is for non-stiff problems, but from the looks of it, it might seem like your problem could be stiff (parameters have a different order of magnitude). Try for instance with the `ode23s` method.
- Secondly, without knowing which event you are looking for, maybe it is possible for you to use a logarithmic search rather than a linear one. e.g. the Bisection method. This will severely cut down on the number of times you have to solve the equation.

Comment: Stiff solvers don't work with the model/ As for the event I am stopping when the solution of one of the variables reaches 1. `function [value, isterminal,direction]=eventfunction(t,y)
    value=y(1)-1;
    isterminal=1;
    direction=0;` Can you please suggest how a bisection method can be implemented.